# SVN- How to commit multiple files in a single shot

Tags: svn, file, commit

I tried to commit multiple files across different directories in a single shot as below,

```
svn commit –m”log msg” mydir/dir1/file1.c mydir/dir2/myfile1.h mydir/dir3/myfile3.c etc etc
```

Since, I wanted to exclude some files from the commit list so I’ve placed each file name in the command line as above. I put it together in the notepad and it came about 25 files.  When I copy and paste it on the command line, the last few files are missing and I guess this might be a command line buffer limitation (?). Is there any option I can increase the buffer length?

Is there any option I can put all files in a text file and give it as an argument to svn commit?

Comment: @Thi - Those who don't use a GUI for subversion are masochists. Get Tortoise SVN or it's Linux equivalent.

Comment: If there is a restriction on buffer length, it won't be in SVN, it will be in whatever shell you are using.

Comment: @cinquTimo: you might prefer to use a GUI for everything. Other people don't.

Comment: @Colin, I think so, how to increase the shell buffer length in that case?

Comment: @Thi: it depends entirely on which shell you are using. I recommend using one of the several suggestions that have been made for SVN

Comment: "Those who don't use a GUI for subversion are masochists." -- Masochism is to use subversion, but some of us have no choice.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use an [svn changelist](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.ref.svn.c.changelist.html) to keep track of a set of files that you want to commit together.

The linked page goes into lots of details, but here's an executive summary example:

```
$ svn changelist my-changelist mydir/dir1/file1.c mydir/dir2/myfile1.h
$ svn changelist my-changelist mydir/dir3/myfile3.c etc.
... (add all the files you want to commit together at your own rate)
$ svn commit -m"log msg" --changelist my-changelist
```

Comment: It has a problem where u added a new folder and a file under that folder. When u add the  folder to changelist, it shows "skipped". When u commit with the changelist, svn showed error E200009: '[folder you added]' is not known to exist in the repository and is not part of the commit, yet its child '[file you added]'' is part of the commit.

Answer (score 32):

You can use `--targets ARG` option where ARG is the name of textfile containing the targets for commit.

```
svn ci --targets myfiles.txt -m "another commit"
```

Comment: Works for me in this bash command: `find . -name \*my.mask | xargs svn ci -m"message" --targets -`

Answer (score 31):

I've had no issues committing a few files like this:

```
svn commit fileDir1/ fileDir2/ -m "updated!"
```

Comment: This is not working for me. Getting error "svn: '/' is not a working copy". Here I have posted my question, you can look. 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/442742/how-to-update-dir-on-svn-server/442751?noredirect=1#442751

Comment: Yes worked nice. Also within my document root i could commit all changes within the working copy tree structure with this:
>svn commit . -m  'mass commit message'

Comment: Works also with files, not only folders :) thanks

Answer (score 3):

Use a changeset. 
You can add as many files as you like to the changeset, all at once, or over several commands; and then commit them all in one go.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.changelists.html  -- The svn keyword is "changelist", which is addressed in the first answer and most upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Same as the [answer by Dmitry Yudakov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336221/8123074), but without an intermediate file, using [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution):

```
svn commit --targets <(echo -e "MyFile1.txt\nMyFile2.txt\n")
```

Comment: For me on FreeBSD this worked only when `-e` added, e.g. `svn commit -m "new version" --targets <(echo -e "file1.ext\nfile2.ext\n")`. Not sure if this is FreeBSD-specific effect or not.